# Hwo to turn off "get_parent_theme_file_path" in child-theme?

Tags: child-theme

I have the Twenty Seventeen theme and I would like to turn off generate SVG (social icons menu) in DOM.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYb49.png

How can I turn off it? I do not use the social icons, but it is g

In function.php my parent theme i see it:

```
require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/icon-functions.php' );
```

How can I override it in my child-theme to avoid generate it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `get_parent_theme_file_path()` it returns `apply_filters( 'parent_theme_file_path', $path, $file );`
You need to add a filter here to override the location to something in your child theme, like so.

```
add_filter('parent_theme_file_path', function($path, $file) {
    if ($file !== '/inc/icon-functions.php') {
        return $path;
    }

    $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file;

    return $path;
}, 10, 2);
```

You will still need to have a file for it to find at that location in your child theme, but you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Okey, but is there possibility to turn off it? Because it still generate the SVG icons to DOM...

Answer (score 1):

Create `/inc/icon-functions.php` file in your child-theme and modify it as you want!

EDIT

You must hook to the `parent_theme_file_path` to tell wordpress load file from child theme, so use the following code:

```
function override_parent_theme_file($path,$file) {
     if ($file == '/inc/icon-functions.php')
          return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file;
}
add_filter('parent_theme_file_path','override_parent_theme_file',10,2);
```

Also you can remove the if statement if you want override to other files included this way.

Comment: `get_parent_theme_file_path` calls `get_template_directory()` which doesn't look in the child theme.  you need to filter it to look in the child theme manually.

Comment: @mrben522 You are right!
I updated my answer to prevent any misunderstanding for anybody.
I hope you consider updating your own answer too and add a simpler way like mine!

Comment: Hello.

You code returns ERROR 500.

Comment: @kibus90 Maybe because you forgot to create `/inc/icon-functions.php` file inside child theme directory!

Comment: I did it! :) I checked twice.

Comment: Could you please set WP_DEBUG to true inside wp-config file and give me the exact error message you get?