# Using filter to override "get_parent_theme_file_path” in child-theme

Tags: child-theme

WRT - [Hwo to turn off "get_parent_theme_file_path" in child-theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325160/hwo-to-turn-off-get-parent-theme-file-path-in-child-theme)

Twenty Seventeen parent theme.

I'm trying to make my child theme over-ride the file /inc/template-tags.php - both my parent theme and child theme have the file in place. (my child version has the adjustments)

The parent enqueues using:

```
require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/template-tags.php' );
```

I have placed the code below in the child function.php

```
add_filter('parent_theme_file_path', function($path, $file) {
if ($file !== '/inc/template-tags.php') {
    return $path;
}

$path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file;

return $path;
}, 10, 2);
```

Unfortunately the parent version of the file is still being used.. What am I missing to override with the child version?

many thanks in advance

Comment: The parent theme uses `get_parent_theme_file_path()` for a reason. This is a signal that you shouldn’t be replacing the whole file in a child theme. If you want to replace template tags then you should copy the just the function into your child theme and modify it there (if it’s pluggable) or create a new function and then replace the original function by copying the template that it’s used in and replacing the original function call with a call to yours.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress [applies](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_path/#source) `ltrim` on the `$file` — `ltrim( $file, '/' )`, so it becomes `inc/template-tags.php` instead of `/inc/template-tags.php`.

So within your filter callback, you should use:

```
if ( $file !== 'inc/template-tags.php' )
```

### UPDATE

> my child version has the adjustments

I don't know if you made adjustments to pluggable or non-pluggable function(s) in the [template file](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/2.1/inc/template-tags.php), but as pointed by @JacobPeattie, you should consider extending parent theme functions like so:

- For *pluggable functions* such as [`twentyseventeen_posted_on`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/2.1/inc/template-tags.php#L12), just copy the whole code and paste it in your `functions.php` file. And then just make your adjustments.

  Pluggable functions are *defined like so*, where the function is wrapped inside a conditional which checks whether a function with the same name already exists or not, and if not, the function is defined:

  ```
  if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) ) :
      function function_name() {
          ...
      }
  endif;
  ```
- For *non-pluggable functions* such as [`twentyseventeen_front_page_section`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/2.1/inc/template-tags.php#L126), follow the same steps above (copy the function code to your `functions.php` file), but make sure to *rename the function* — e.g. `my_theme_front_page_section` or `my_twentyseventeen_front_page_section`.

  And after you renamed the function, make sure to change the name in template files where the function is being called. For example, `twentyseventeen_front_page_section` is being called in the [front page (`front-page.php`) template](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/2.1/front-page.php#L46), so you'd change `twentyseventeen_front_page_section( null, $i );` to `my_theme_front_page_section( null, $i );` (if you renamed the function to `my_theme_front_page_section`).

I could understand that it might be a hassle to do the renaming part, but particularly for *pluggable* functions, you don't need to override the template file using the `parent_theme_file_path` filter (or similar filter). The function(s) you're trying to modify might also actually have *filters* you can simply hook into to customize/change the function output, so be sure to check that. :)